# Jest test for koa application getting an error as "TypeError: app.address is not a function"

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, koa, supertest

I want to create my tests. I build a server with koa.js and my server.ts file like that:

```
import Koa from "koa";
import jwt from "koa-jwt";
import bodyParser from "koa-bodyparser";

...
...


    const app = new Koa();

    
    app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
            scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "cdnjs.cloudflare.com"],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "cdnjs.cloudflare.com", "fonts.googleapis.com"],
            fontSrc: ["'self'", "fonts.gstatic.com"],
            imgSrc: ["'self'", "data:", "online.swagger.io", "validator.swagger.io"]
        }
    }));

    
    app.use(cors());


    app.use(logger(winston));


    app.use(bodyParser());

    app.use(unprotectedRouter.routes()).use(unprotectedRouter.allowedMethods());

    app.use(jwt({ secret: config.jwtSecret }).unless({ path: [/^\/swagger-/] }));

    app.use(protectedRouter.routes()).use(protectedRouter.allowedMethods());

    cron.start();

    app.listen(config.port, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port ${config.port}`);
    });
    export default app;
```

And my test.ts file like that:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../../src/server';

describe('basic route tests', () => {
    test('get home route GET /', async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get('/');
    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(response.text).toContain('Hello World!');
    });
});
```

So, Im getting an error as:

[image]

Why Im getting this error? I think the problem occurred with exporting app.
How Can I solve this error?

Comment: The default export from server is the promise chain from createConnection, not the app.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I made changes for escaping chain form but I getting same error. I edited my question.